# How to create and add js and css file when server is not on my PC?

Tags: php, themes, css, javascript

I have to create and add a javascript and a css file and add that to wordpress theme.

problem is server is on other computer.

So I can't add js and css file so simply.

I know I can edit theme If i navigate to mysiteurl.com/theme-editor.php

but I don't know how to add file to theme.

How should I do?

because server is on the another PC, i don't know direction and url of the theme

I know just url of site

Answer (score 0):

You need either FTP access or access to the cPanel. If you could do it with only the URL, anyone could add and run scripts on any website.